# How to track dynamically generated manipulators?

Tags: manipulate

In the code below the manipulators that are generated from the stakes buttons are not tracked by the `Manipulate` expression that contains them.

How can I make the plot update with these sliders? If I add 'stakeWeights' and 'roi' (the values of the manipulators) to the tracked symbols, the manipulators won't move.

My apologies for posting the complete code but I couldn't find an easy way to isolate this from the rest of the code.

```
RandomWalk[n_, roi_, bi_, rake_] :=
 (*If errors return list with zero so ListPlot does not complain *)
 Quiet@Check[(pwin = bi (1 + roi)/(2 (bi - rake)); 
    NestWhileList[# + RandomChoice[{pwin, 1 - pwin} -> {1 - 2 rake/bi, -1}] &, 
      0, True &, 0, n]), 
    {0}]

trial = 0;
allStakes = {1.5, 3.5, 7, 15, 30, 60, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000};
rakes = {0.06, 0.1, 0.15, 0.31, 0.63, 1.26, 1.88, 3.34, 4.49, 6.65, 11.2}
MapIndexed[(rakebyStake[#1] = rakes[[#2]]) &, allStakes]    

Manipulate[trial;
 data = RandomWalk[nrTournaments, avgROI/100, avgBI, avgRake];
 (stakeWeights[#] = 100) & /@ allStakes;
 (roi[#] = 1) & /@ allStakes;
 avgBI = 
  Quiet@Check[
    Total[(# stakeWeights[#]/Total[stakeWeights /@ stakes]) & /@ 
       stakes // N], 0];
 avgRake = 
  Quiet@Check[
    Total[(rakebyStake[#][[1]] stakeWeights[#]/
           Total[stakeWeights /@ stakes]) & /@ stakes // N], 0];
 avgROI = 
  Quiet@Check[
    Total[(roi[#] stakeWeights[#]/Total[stakeWeights /@ stakes]) & /@ 
       stakes // N], 0];
 biWon = Quiet@Check[Last[data], 0]; dollarWon = biWon avgBI; 
 pwin = Quiet@Check[avgBI (1 + avgROI/100)/(2 (avgBI - avgRake)), 0];
 expectedBiWon = 
  Quiet@Check[((1 - 2 avgRake/avgBI) pwin - (1 - pwin)) nrTournaments, 0];
 expectedDollarWon = expectedBiWon avgBI;
 sampleROI = Quiet@Check[dollarWon/(nrTournaments avgBI), 0];
 Dynamic@ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0.2, 0.6]}], 
 {{nrTournaments, 3000, "tournaments"}, 0, 100000, 100, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{stakes, {60}, "stakes"}, allStakes, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
 Dynamic[Column@{Grid[({#, 
         Manipulator[Dynamic[stakeWeights[#]], {0, 100, 1}], 
         Dynamic[Quiet@
           Check[100 stakeWeights[#]/
              Total[stakeWeights /@ stakes // N], 0]],
         "ROI", 
         Manipulator[Dynamic[roi[#]], {0, 75}, 
          Appearance -> "Labeled"]}) & /@ Sort[stakes]]}],
 {{avgROI, 1.5, "avg ROI (%)"}, 0, 75, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 {{avgBI, 60, "avg BI ($)"}, 0, 10000, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
     {{avgRake, 1.26, "avg rake ($)"}, 0, avgBI/10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
     {{rakeback, 37, "rakeback (%)"}, 0, 100, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
     Delimiter, 
     Panel[Grid[{{Dynamic[
          Row[{"sample ROI: ", 
            Style[ToString[sampleROI 100] <> "%", 
             If[sampleROI >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]]}]]}, {Dynamic[
          Row[{"# BI won: ", ToString[biWon], " (", 
            Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
             If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], ")"}]]},
        {Dynamic[
          Row[{"rakeback: ", 
            Style["$" <> ToString[avgRake rakeback/100 nrTournaments], 
             Darker[Green]]}]]}, {Dynamic[
          Row[{"$ won after rakeback: ", 
            Style["$" <> 
              ToString[dollarWon + avgRake rakeback/100 nrTournaments], 
             If[dollarWon + avgRake rakeback /100 nrTournaments >= 0, 
              Darker[Green], Red]]}]]},
        {Dynamic[
          Row[{"expected # BI won: ", ToString[expectedBiWon], " (", 
            Style["$" <> ToString[expectedDollarWon], 
         If[expectedDollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], ")"}]]}}, 
   Alignment -> Left]], 
 Button["Run again", trial++, ImageSize -> Medium], 
 SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {nrTournaments, avgROI, avgBI, avgRake, trial, 
   stakes, rakeback}]
```

Comment: You really should make an attempt to reduce your problem to an example that reproduces it in far fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your manipulators don't move because of the lines

```
(stakeWeights[#] = 100) & /@ allStakes;
(roi[#] = 1) & /@ allStakes;
```

inside the `Manipulate`. Just pull those lines outside.

On a related note, I was playing around and found this kind of control that you might benefit/get ideas from:

```
adaptoControl[Dynamic[settings_]] := Dynamic[
   Column[MapIndexed[Function[{val, position},
      Manipulator[Dynamic[settings[[Sequence @@ position]]]]],
     settings, {3}]]];
```

Usage:

```
stakes = {1.5, 3.5, 7, 15, 30};
settings = # -> {0, 1} & /@ stakes;
{adaptoControl[Dynamic[settings]], Dynamic[Column[settings]]}
```

[image]

Also you can construct your `Manipulate` piecemeal using various methods:

```
controls = Sequence[{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}];
Manipulate[
 {u, v},
 Evaluate[controls]]

With[{controls = Sequence[{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]},
 Manipulate[
  {u, v},
  controls]]
```

Comment: `Sequence` is not needed when there is only one control. A better example is `With[{controls = Sequence[{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]}, Manipulate[{u, v}, controls]]`

Comment: @m_goldberg That's good, I'll add it. I was tryng to keep the examples "minimally general". Funnily, it wouldn't have occured to me to apply `Sequence` that way.